# bazel build: failing to link external non-bazel shared library

Tags: build, compilation, shared-libraries, bazel, .so

I am experimenting with Bazel for the first time. I am trying to build a shared library using Bazel-3.7.2. The shared library has an external non-Bazel library dependency. After Bazel build I get the new shared library ".so" file. But using ldd I cannot find the external dependency.

The WORKSPACE file looks as follows. Here libxed.so is the extern shared library.

```
# xed library
new_local_repository(
    name = "libxed",
    path = "dependencies/xed/kits/xed-install-base",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "libxed",
    srcs = ["lib/libxed.so"],
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/xed/*.h",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

# xed header files
new_local_repository(
    name = "libxed_headers",
    path = "dependencies/xed/kits/xed-install-base/include/xed",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "xed",
    hdrs = glob([
        "*.h",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)
```

The BUILD file:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "themis",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/main.cpp",
        "src/tools/Themis/*.cpp",
        ],
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "includes/tools/Themis/mytool.hpp",
    ]),
    strip_include_prefix = "includes",
    linkopts = ["-pthread", "-lrt", "-lunwind", "-ldl"],
    deps = [
       "@libxed_headers//:xed",
       "@libxed//:libxed",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

After building the library it creates libthemis.so.

```
ldd bazel-bin/libthemis.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe410ab000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f70e7de8000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f70e7a4a000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f70e7842000)
        libunwind.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so.8 (0x00007f70e7627000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70e7423000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f70e7204000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70e6e13000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f70e8171000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f70e6bfb000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f70e69d5000)
```

Here libthemis.so does not include libxed.so. Note that I can build the Themis library with Cmake correctly. How can I fix the Bazel build?

Comment: For first you should not create separate libraries. Create only one, which will be self sufficient (headers and *.so).

Comment: Regarding the question: can you show content of file, which should be named like this `bazel-bin/libthemis.so-2.params` (or something similar). It should contains arguments, which are passed to linker during a final linking

Comment: The libthemis.so-2.params looks like this: https://gist.github.com/proywm/0280404390f0ef7e6e31dfc35bcca35f

Comment: I was able to build the library by adding an additional cc_binary block:https://gist.github.com/proywm/d496267b3f41ffb4f961f2d0f0e687ce . After adding cc_binary I was able to see libxed.so depenendency in libthemis.so. Can you please explain why?

Comment: It may be a little counter-intuitive, but you build solib by declaring `cc_binary` with `linkshared` set to `True`. The reason being, yes, solib is a library (as the name suggests), but it's also a final product of linking and that is performed in the binary rule. So I suppose the way to remember: need a linker, use `cc_binary`.